# How can I pass a URL from Javascript to Java module

Tags: javascript, java, rest

I want to send URL string to a java module whenever a user clicks on chrome extension.

Here's my JS code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

      chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function (tabs) {
      alert(tabs[0].url)
      var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var someValue = "http://chums/chummi";

        var url = "http://localhost:8080/SalesRESTservice/apicall/restcall2/";

        http.open("GET", url, true);

        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
        http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

        http.send(someValue);
    });
  });
```

Here's my Java

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

@Path("/restcall2")
public class restcall2 {


      @Path("{f}")
      @GET
      @Produces("text/plain")
      public Response RESTcall(@PathParam("f") String f) throws JSONException {
        return Response.status(200).entity(f).build();
      }

}
```

Whenever I try to hit URL `http://localhost:8080/SalesRESTservice/apicall/restcall2/`
I get no response.
In my network tab it shows
[image]

I am using **Tomcat** server to service the request

Comment: Don't know why i am getting 405 error code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is at your Java side
Try changing your java code

- USE POST
- Avoid path param
  & remove @path{f}, this will ensure no other
  value will not hit URL

  ```
  import javax.ws.rs.GET;
  @Path("/restcall2")
  public class restcall2 {      
    @POST
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public Response RESTcall(String f) throws JSONException {
        System.out.println(f);
      return Response.status(200).entity("hello " + f).build();
    }
  ```

  }

Answer (score 0):

405 - method not allowed

Your server is not listening for the url.

Try also GET /restcall2/somevalue

Check your deployment configuration and server logs. With provided info it is not possible to guess what is failing on server part

About the general project:. You should change GET to POST to avoid URL encoding problems

http.send(someValue) is for POST requests

Do not use encoding aplicación/json if you do not use json. For the example you could use

POST /restcall2
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
myurl=someValue

And in server part

```
   @POST
@Path("/")
public Response RESTcall(
    @FormParam("myurl") String url
```